# use load() with fadeout fadein to replace the content

Tags: jquery, html

how use `load()` function of jquery with fadein and fadeout to load from another page?

```
 $( ".content_here" ).fadeOut("slow").load("each_article_content.php","id="+id).fadeIn("slow")
```

but it dont work correctly

Answer (score 2):

You need to use function callback, they are alled when the action is done:

```
$( ".content_here" ).fadeOut("slow", function(){
    $(this).load("each_article_content.php","id="+id, function(){
        $(this).fadeIn("slow")
    })
})
```

Comment: I was going to comment the same like @Karl-André